# HTTP 404 Resource not found - Grafana World Map Plugin Custom Marker

Tags: leaflet, grafana

I am trying to use custom Markers with Grafana World Map Plugin using the Leaflet JS Library. But even after i place the Custom Marker image in the Source Directory i keep getting the below error-

```
http://localhost:3000/datacenter.png 404 (Not Found)
```

My code looks like this -

```
var dataCenterIcon = window.L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'datacenter.png',
    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

window.L.marker([caponeDCLat, caponeDCLong], {icon: dataCenterIcon}).addTo(this.map);
```

Can anyone provide some inputs as to what i may be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a Grafana plugin, the paths are relative to Grafana home page.

Here is an example from the WorldPing App:

`<img src="public/plugins/raintank-worldping-app/img/loading-pulse.svg"`

See:

https://github.com/raintank/worldping-app/blob/master/dist/components/probe/partials/probe_list.html#L11